# Routing php mvc

Tags: php, url-routing

I need help with router when i enter route in href for example

Login

Register

first link i click works 
url is localhost/account/login

but second time i click link url is localhost/account/account/register

```
function __construct(){
    $arr = require 'application/config/routes.php';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $this->add($key, $val);
    }

}

public function add($route, $params) {
    $route = '#^'.$route.'$#';
    $this->routes[$route] = $params;
}

public function match() {
    $url = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    foreach ($this->routes as $route => $params) {
        if (preg_match($route, $url, $matches)) {
            $this->params = $params;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function run(){
    if($this->match()){
        $path = 'application\controllers\\'.ucfirst($this->params['controller']).'Controller';
        if(class_exists($path)){
          $action = $this->params['action'].'Action';
          if (method_exists($path, $action)){
                $controller = new $path($this->params);
                $controller->$action();
          }else{
            View::errorCode(404);
          }
        }else{
           View::errorCode(404);
        }
    }else{
        View::errorCode(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you output the links in your HTML.

Comment: <a href="account/register">Register</a>

Comment: return [
    
    '' =>[
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action' => 'index',
    ],
    
    'account/login' =>[
        'controller' => 'account',
        'action' => 'login',
    ],
    
    'account/register' => [
        'controller' => 'account',
        'action' => 'register',
    ],
];

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question to contain _all_ relevant code.

Comment: Start your links with `/` like this: `<a href="/account/register">...</a>`. That will make them relative from the document root instead of from the current URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL's don't start with `/`, so they are relative to the current URL. Please add a `/` before.

Your code now:

```
<a href="account/register">Register</a>
```

Change it to:

```
<a href="/account/register">Register</a>
```